# How to solve this "TypeError" message in Python?

Tags: python, syntax, typeerror, jupyter-notebook

I am new to Python. I have the following line of code running in Jupyter Notebook where I am doing a scatterplot:

```
colors = ["#%02x%02x%02x" %(r,g,150) for r, g in zip(np.floor(50+2*x), np.floor(30+2*y))]
```

When I run this piece of code, Python throws out the following error message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-ec6675e13d1f> in <module>()
----> 1 colors = ["#%02x%02x%02x" %(r,g,150) for r, g in zip(np.floor(50+2*x), np.floor(30+2*y))]

<ipython-input-9-ec6675e13d1f> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 colors = ["#%02x%02x%02x" %(r,g,150) for r, g in zip(np.floor(50+2*x), np.floor(30+2*y))]

TypeError: %x format: an integer is required, not numpy.float64
```

What is causing this error and how do I solve it?

Comment: By making `r` and `g` integers?

Comment: try `["#%02x%02x%02x" %(int(r),int(g),150) for r, g in zip(np.floor(50+2*x), np.floor(30+2*y))]` leave in-line method if not work.

Comment: @dsgdfg Thanks! Works beautifully! Can you post it as an answer so that I can give it the vote?

Comment: But, this @AndrewLi point not my  ! Tell him, sorry for that!

Comment: @AndrewLi Thanks Andrew, please post as an answer.

Comment: @dsgdfg Don't need the points, just trying to help. Post an answer as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Andrew Li and "dsgdfg" for pointing me in the right direction.

Changing the code to the following did the trick:

```
["#%02x%02x%02x" %(int(r),int(g),150) for r, g in zip(np.floor(50+2*x), np.floor(30+2*y))]
```